# Unable to get repeating daily notification to show with UNUserNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

My goal is to set up a repeating daily reminder notification. The following code always successfully show the notification *once*, but does not repeat it, despite setting `repeat: true` in the code.

The entire notification code is below:

```
    let notificationID = "daily_sleep_alarm"
    let title = "Rest your weary eyes"
    let body = "It's bedtime. The comfort of your blanket beckons you."

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [notificationID])
    
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = body
    content.categoryIdentifier = "daily_sleep_alarm"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
    content.sound = nil

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = hourSelected
    dateComponents.minute = minuteSelected
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationID, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
```

As noted above, this code does not successfully show the notification after once. I have no other code that clears pending notifications with this particular `notificationID`.

On app start, I also check to see what pending notifications are available with `center.getPendingNotificationRequests`, and it always shows as none.

Any insights on what I need to do to correctly set up the daily repeating notification is muched appreciated.

Comment: Are you checking user permissions for notification access before this?

Comment: @KaylaGalway thanks for the input. I am indeed checking permission. This is also the issue on my test devices, which all have permissions allowed.

Answer (score 0):

i'm just using this simple lines of code for daily

```
    func setNotifications(with interval: TimeInterval) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Tittle"
    content.subtitle = "Subtle"
    content.body = "Don't forget yourself!"
    content.badge = 1
    
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval,
                                                    repeats: true)
    
    let requestIdentifier = "demoNotification"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request,
                                           withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
                                            // Handle error
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grigory. What is the time interval you have set in the code, and how is this populated?

Comment: It's just seconds double value